# Why will my UIColor not create properly?

Tags: ios, colors, uibutton, rgb, uicolor

I need help! I'm very new to this and I am trying to make a UIButton with a fill color, but every time I try to create my UIColor to fill it with it doesn't work.

When I use:

```
UIColor *orangeButtonColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIButton *firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(6, 9, 64, 64);
[firstButton setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
firstButton.backgroundColor = orangeButtonColor;
[self.view addSubview:firstButton];
```

It gives my a black button on my screen, but I want a custom colored button using RGB colors (actually CMYK is my preference, but I can't make that work either). So I change my code to this:

```
UIColor *orangeButtonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:246 green:180 blue:119 alpha:1];
UIButton *firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(6, 9, 64, 64);
[firstButton setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
firstButton.backgroundColor = orangeButtonColor;
[self.view addSubview:firstButton];
```

And then there is nothing on the screen where the button just was, only white. I don't understand why I would be getting this problem, but some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: want you to read the following document very carefully:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

Does this tell you why your color is always white?

(Hint: Check the section on + colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:)

Answer (score 3):

Try dividing your color by 255. Try the following

```
  UIColor *orangeButtonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.0 green:180/255.0 blue:119/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Let me know if it works or you need any more help.